# searching for fantasy series: assassin (?), ship, fated lovers, sound of drums, and shapeshifter (?)

Tags: story-identification

I'm trying to find a book I read several years ago, it's been impossible for me to pull this title up with my search terms. I'm hoping against hope that someone can recognize this series! I can't get this dynamic out of my head.

It's a fantasy series and there are at least three books and I believe a book preceding it that's unrelated to the main story line.

The main character is a girl, I believe she is an assassin, or some kind of a guardswoman. She is pursuing (?) something, either a man, or that man is some antagonistic group, who is perhaps searching for the same thing?

She determines that in some way they are drawn together. They have a psychic link. He pursues her, and midway through the first book, they finally encounter one another, there's a chase-- I believe there is some implication of heightened senses or being a shapeshifter or wolves or some sort (?)

When they meet and get intimate the first time, the narration talks about drums in the street... or maybe downstairs, or maybe just in their head.

Afterwards she flees, devastaing him and leaving them both with this pining connection for one another. I believe they can, to some distance, communicate psychically.

She winds up on a ship... eventually with him? or some other guy. I believe there are some ruins?

The final book is about an approaching army of some beast or monster or demonic race, and a woman who is pregant and psychically linked to her child. They're marching on the main city.

Any one have any clue?

You would be the source of HUGE relief!

Comment: any out-of-universe details you can remember? when did you read it? any idea when it was published? even descriptions of the book covers can help.

Comment: Thanks for chiming in! I definitely read it before 2007.  I'm pretty sure weaponry is sword based, and there's no guns, etc. I believe I remember the city possibly being built into a cliff? But I can't be sure. I'm also sure that the heroine wore pants, if that helps. I don't believe there are any wizards per se

Comment: By some miracle... (being Google advanced search) I actually tracked it down ... its called Diplomacy of Wolves by Holly Lisle. Turns out I couldn't find it at my library because they don't have the book anymore.

Comment: For four centuries the houses of Sabir and Galweigh have battled for control of Calimekka, while the clan's wizards, the Wolves, plot to revive the hellish necromancies that once destroyed the world. When a young diplomat named Kait discovers a plot to ambush the entire Galweigh house, she must decide whether to use her innate gift--a power so feared that her own people will kill her if its nature were discovered.

Comment: @OhNo Good job on finding it! Please do answer your own question; you'll get upvotes for it, and then after a day or two you can 'accept' your answer as the correct one. (Btw, this sounds like it might be a fun series to read - thanks for the recommendation, I guess ;-) )

Comment: Thanks for the tip @randal'thor !! Let me know if you get a chance to read :) It's certainly what I'm going to be doing tonight. Savoring the feeling of sweet vindication.

Answer (score 4):

Found via some lucky Google Advance Search -- This is the Holly Lisle series, The Diplomacy of Wolves, Vengeance of Dragons, Courage of Falcons.

A kind of Romeo & Juliet story with a war brewing over the restriction of necromatic magic.